# Trying to move from Angular 1.5x to ReactJS, what is the best way to A/B test and experiment with the views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, abtest

So, I have been moving part of the UI code to ReactJS, for instrumentation I wanted to A/B test my app, so that it can be easily configured. I heard from somewhere that Intuit's Wasabi is a great framework but i disliked its overhead of setting up in production. I want something that can be easily configured and yet the data remains inhouse.

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple solution in React you can create a random function that displays one of two components ( A/B test ) when either of the components is displayed it fires an event to Google Analytics that tells you that the person who visited received either the A  or B component..

As long as you have all the other events tracked for conversion on the website, analytics you should be able to get the results you need.

Other than that i am unaware of any open source and free applications that will run your A/B tests for you unless you build it yourself?

depending on traffic you could try https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize

although the data would be housed in the optimize application.